# Xamarin forms TabbedPage Call the Xaml Page with parameter

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can i call a Xaml Page that has a parameter?

This is my xaml code:

```
<TabbedPage .....>

    <local1:CustomizedPage Title="Customized" />
    <local1:NotePage Title="Note" />

</TabbedPage>
```

Basically the customizedPage does have Parameter.
This is my CustomizedPage.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class CustomizedPage : ContentPage
    {
        private DevotionalViewModel _devotional;

        public CustomizedPage (DevotionalViewModel devotional)
        {
            if (devotional != null)
            {
                _devotional = devotional;
            }


            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `x:Argument` attribute:

```
<TabbedPage .....>

    <local1:CustomizedPage Title="Customized" x:Arguments="{StaticResource myValue}" />
    <local1:NotePage Title="Note" />

</TabbedPage>
```

You can pass something in through a static resource or with a factory method.

For more info, see the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/passing-arguments

The other alternative of course is to do it through code.

Comment: bro, thanks for the answer but it gives me error like this: The attribute 'Arguments' from the XAML namespace is not defined.

Comment: Are you using the `x:` before it?

Comment: Yes sir. <local1:CustomizedPage Title="Customized" x:Arguments="{StaticResource myValue}" />

Comment: You are probably missing `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"` at the start of the page.